# BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request - While sending email from EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-ses

I am using Django (Pyhton) framework deployed on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance and sending email using BOTO and AWS SES service.
Earlier my script used to work.
But since few days I have encountered an error:

```
BotoServerError at /contact_us/
BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>RequestExpired</Code>
    <Message>Request timestamp: Wed, 16 Mar 2016 16:57:21 GMT expired.  It must be within 300 secs/ of server time.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>368a4b97-eb97-11e5-bf2d-8ff0675b134d</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

> **Exception Location:**   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ses/connection.py
>   in _handle_error, line 177
>
> **Server time:**  Wed, 16 Mar 2016 16:57:21 +0000

The SES is working on UTC and I have changed the time of EC2 to UTC as well.
Help me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Request timestamp: Wed, 16 Mar 2016 16:57:21 GMT expired.  It
>   must be within 300 secs/ of server time.

Since you said it is not working for few days, it is most likely due to recent daylight savings time. And it is likely you are not running ntp to sync your clock.

Try this: `sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org`

which will sync your system clock. If you want to make sure the time sync happens periodically, then start the NTP daemon:

```
sudo service ntp stop
sudo ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org
sudo service ntp start
```

Comment: This happened to us as well. For the past few months it's working and then suddenly got the error. Run this command and it fixed it. Will this be a recurring thing?

Comment: This seems a recurring event . Any idea how to resolve this.?

Comment: @helloV Thank you, Right now I have set a cron job to run two times a day. Do you know how  often this daemon will update the time ? Is it like whenever the time goes wrong ?

Comment: Goodness me this saved me a lot of hours trying to figure out what the hell was going on. Thanks.